# Acronyms with dotfill LaTex

Tags: acronyms

I am using \dotfill with my acronyms and everything is working fine. But when I am referring to an acronym in the text LaTex also includes the dots. Is there a way to use dotfill without having the dots in the text afterwards?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,
twoside,
BCOR=10mm, 
DIV=calc,  
titlepage=on,
idxtotoc,
xcolor = pdftex,
dvipsnames,
bibliography=totoc,
liststotoc
]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
      \acro{cta}[CTA]{\dotfill Constant Temperature Anemometer}
\end{acronym}

       Test \ac{cta}

\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\Ac{imho}, is better not to \ac{rw}. \Ac{rtfm} could help to follow the \acfi{kiss} principle. Always  \ac{imho}, and only \acl{imho}. 
\newpage 
\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[YesIcan]
      \acro{imho}[IMHO]{\acroextra{\dotfill}in my humble opinion}
      \acro{kiss}[KISS]{\acroextra{\dotfill}keep it simple and small}
     \acro{rtfm}[RTFM]{\acroextra{\dotfill}read the fine manual}
     \acro{rw}[NTRTW]{\acroextra{\dotfill}reinvent the wheel}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can patch the `acronym` environment (actually some weirdly defined command).

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  twoside,
  BCOR=10mm, 
  DIV=calc,  
  titlepage=on,
  index=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  listof=totoc,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname AC@\AC@prefix{}@acro\endcsname
 {#1]{#3}}
 {#1]\dotfill\ {#3}}
 {}{}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname AC@\AC@prefix{}@acro\endcsname
 {#1]{#3}}
 {#1]\dotfill\ {#3}}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{cta}[CTA]{Constant Temperature Anemometer}
\end{acronym}

       Test \ac{cta}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's necessary to do the patch twice, because the code is almost duplicated for the cases when `hyperref` is loaded or not.

I changed a couple of document class options in order to avoid annoying warnings. Also `xcolor` is not an option to `scrreprt`.

Comment: You did the patch twice.

Comment: @SimonDispa Yes, it's necessary, because the code does similar things to cope when `hyperref` is loaded or not. I added the reason to my answer, thanks for noting the need for it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\Ac{imho}, is better not to \ac{rtw}. \Ac{rtfm} could help to follow the \acfi{kiss} principle. Always  \ac{imho}, and only \acl{imho}. 
\newpage 
\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[YesWeCan]
      \acro{imho}[IMHO]{\acroextra{\dotfill}in my humble opinion}
      \acro{kiss}[KISS]{\acroextra{\dotfill}keep it simple and small}
     \acro{rtfm}[RTFM]{\acroextra{\dotfill}read the fine manual}
     \acro{rtw}[RTW]{\acroextra{\dotfill}reinvent the whell}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```